# How can I use MVC ideas without using classes?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

As of right now, I am still shaky on classes, so I don't want to use any classes for my site. I'm still practicing with classes.

But how can I implement the MVC idea without classes?

> Would this work for a MVC?
>
> index.php (the view)
>
> index_controller.php
>
> index_model.php

```
    Is this right for what a MVC should be? 
View: show html, css, forms 
Controller: get $_POST from forms and any data from the user, get info from db 
Model: do all the functions, insert/delete in db, etc
```

Basically separate the HTML/css for the view, all the data collecting for the controller, and the logic for the model. And just connect them all using require_once.

Comment: Yes you can do it, see Rasmus's implementation of a minimal MVC - http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html. He used classes for DB and Model, but you can swap those out with functions. *But **why** don't you want to use classes?*

Comment: I'm still new to classes so I don't want to use it without first practicing with smaller projects. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Controller*: Your `index.php`, accepting and directing requests. This can certainly be a 'classless' script. It would act as both controller and 'front controller'.

*View(s)*: A collection of presentation scripts, specific script included by your controller. Essentially 'getting' data from the variable scope of the controller.

*Model(s)*: A collection of functions that provide access to your data. The controller determines what to include for a request.

Sure, it *can* be done, but you loose a lot not using classes (OOP). Here's a quick **example** of what the controller **might** look like. Nothing amazing, just an idea. Showing the controller should shed some light on the model/view as well.

```
<?php
  $action = getAction(); //parse the request to find the action
  switch($action){
    case 'list':
      include('models/todolist.php'); //include the model
      $items = todolistGetItems(); //get the items using included function
      include('views/todolist/list.php'); //include the view
      break;
    case 'add':
      if(!empty($_POST['new'])){ 
        include('models/todolist.php'); //include the model
        todolistAddItem($_POST); //add the item
        $items = todolistGetItems(); //get the items using included function
        include('views/todolist/list.php'); //include the view
      } else {
        include('views/todolist/add.php'); //include the view
      }
  }
```